# Separate Sitemaps for Each Language with Polylang and Yoast SEO

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, sitemap, plugin-polylang

I have a WordPress website with two essential plugins, Polylang for multilingual support and Yoast SEO for sitemap generation. Currently, the sitemap can be accessed through **mysite.com/sitemap_index.xml** containing URLs of all sitemaps of my site, and **mysite.com/post-sitemap.xml** contains URLs of posts from all languages.
[image: sitemap_index xml]

However, I would like to have separate sitemaps for each language. For instance, I aim to have **mysite.com/ar/post-sitemap.xml** containing URLs of all Arabic language posts and **mysite.com/ru/sitemap_index.xml** containing URLs of all Russian language posts.

Could anyone kindly provide guidance on how to achieve this using Polylang and Yoast SEO plugins or do I need to use a separate plugin for it? Any insights, code snippets, or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separated sitemap for each language like your example above, or add an alternate URL for each item for each language in a sitemap.

The first approach requires adding custom rewrite rules to WordPress, and add some queries to get all posts within a language. This is a big job and should be done by the plugins. I think SEO plugin should do that, if they go this way.

The second approach works better since it doesn't require custom rewrite rules or queries. Instead of that, it only add alternate URLs for each language (which are provided by multilingual plugin like Polylang) to each post in the sitemap. You don't need to change/add your sitemap URL, just add more content to that. To see the URLs, you must view the source code of the sitemap.

I think most SEO plugin automatically adds integration for popular multilingual plugins. You can verify this by viewing the source code of the sitemap for posts.

If you need more details about these approaches, Slim SEO wrote a [detailed blog post](https://wpslimseo.com/wordpress-multilingual-sitemap/) about this.

Comment: I have read that blog, Slim SEO uses the second approach, which is only one sitemap for all languages. However, I want to use the first approach which is a separate sitemap for each language on the website. Could you please share some details on how can I implement the first approach?

Comment: To implement the 1st approach, you'll need to replicate the steps that SEO plugins do to create their sitemap:

- Register a custom rewrite rule & custom query variable for your sitemap
- Parse the query to catch the requests for your sitemap
- Query posts to output for the sitemap

I assume this is a lot of work, and it's a duplication of what sitemap feature in SEO plugins does.